# JLabel showing ellipses when is has space to show full label

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

JLabel showing ellipses when is has space to show full label

[image: Image of it]

my code:

```
​import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel;

import com.bulenkov.darcula.DarculaLaf;

public class GUI implements ActionListener {
    
    private int count = 0;
    private JLabel label;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    
    public GUI() throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException  {
        
        BasicLookAndFeel darcula = new DarculaLaf();
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(darcula);
        
        frame = new JFrame();
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        
        label = new JLabel("Number of clicks: 0");
        
        
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 100, -85, 100));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(label);
        
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        ///frame.setTitle("Cool GUI");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        new GUI();
        
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        count++;
        label.setText("Number of clicks: " + count);
    }

}
```

Comment: Set the preferred size of the JLabel to be large enough to hold the text string.  Or add a JTextField to hold the count.

Comment: Gilbert Le Blanc how would I go about doing that, sorry im quite new to java

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a good tutorial that teaches the basics of Swing, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.

I created the following GUI.

[image: Basic GUI]

Here's what I did.

1. I started my Swing GUI with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that all of the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
2. I separated the code to construct the `JFrame` from the code to construct the `JPanel`.  The `JFrame` methods have to be called in a certain order.  This is the order I use for most of my Swing applications.
3. I construct the `JPanel` in Swing component order.  I keep all methods having to do with a particular Swing component together.
4. I put the "Number of clicks:" text in one place.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class BasicGUI implements ActionListener, Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new BasicGUI());  
    }
    
    private int count;
    
    private JLabel label;
    
    public BasicGUI() {
        this.count = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cool GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(button);
        
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        updateLabel(0);
        panel.add(label);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public void updateLabel(int count) {
        label.setText("Number of clicks: " + count);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        updateLabel(++count);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think GridBagLayout asks your JLabel about the required size when the UI is initialized. Then the JLabel is assigned the requested size.

During runtime the String that needs to be displayed by the JLabel changes, and actually it gets longer. But no re-layout is happening, therefore the JLabel is not allowed to use more space - even if on the screen it seems there is plenty of space.

The solution is to either tell GridBagLayout to reserve plenty of space for that component, or allow for dynamic scaling. Check the [GridBagLayout tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
BasicLookAndFeel darcula = new DarculaLaf();
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(darcula);
```

Don't use a 3rd party LAF when asking a basic question.

We don't know if the problem is related to the LAF or the standard classes of the JDK.

> JLabel showing ellipses when is has space to show full label

Well actually it doesn't have space because you use the `pack()` method and all components are displayed at their preferred size based on the preferred size of the components and of the Borders applied to the components.

When I run your code (using the default LAF) the text displays correctly at startup.

This is because the width of the panel is controlled by the preferred width of the JButton since it is the larger component.

However, if I change the text of the button to be:

```
label.setText("Number of clicks made: " + count);
```

now the width of the panel is controlled by the preferred width of the label since it is greater than that of the button.

Again, at startup the text displays properly

However, if you click the button 10 times then the "count" changes from a one digit number to a two digit number which increases the preferred size of the label causing the "..." to appear.

A simple solution is to use:

```
count++;
label.setText("Number of clicks made: " + count);
frame.pack();
```

Now the frame will be resized to accommodate the newly calculated preferred size of the label.

```
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
```

Also, don't hardcode the "rows" of the GridLayout. The above code reserves space for 5 components even though you only have 2.

Instead use:

```
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
```

which indicates a single column with any number of components.

Then you can use the EmptyBorder properly to give it symmetry on all sides:

```
//panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 100, -85, 100));
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 100, 20, 100));
```